# Replacing impossible values with NA using R's data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a code that replaces impossible values in a dataset with NA.

I'm trying to convert the code to being based on `data.table`, as an example, I replace height of `0` with height `NA`

(Dummy) data

```
 DT <- data.table(id = 1:5e6, 
                  height = sample(c(0, 100:240), 5e6, replace = TRUE))
```

My current solution is slower and at least as verbose as my data.frame version. I assume I am doing something wrong...

```
DT[height == 0, height := NA]
```

While researching this question I found another solution which is much faster (but uglier).

```
set(DT, which("height"==0), "height", value = NA)
```

All suggestions appreciated.

Comment: `DT[height == 0, height := NA]` is slow?

Comment: Your researched solution does not work for me

Comment: @PierreLafortune it should be something like `set(DT, i = which(DT[["height"]] == 0), j = "height", value = NA)` I guess

Comment: That's faster than the rest @DavidArenburg

Comment: Thanks @DavidArenburg.

Comment: @PierreLafortune My mistake: "faster (but uglier)." solution that I had been using `set(DT, which(DT$height==0), "height", value = NA)`.
`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `v1.9.4`, *data.table* by default automatically creates an index on columns during subsets of the form `x == val` and `x %in% val` used within `[.data.table` call. This makes subsequent subsetting very fast with only a slightly higher price to pay on the first subset (since data.table's radix ordering is quite fast). The first subset could be slower because it is the time to:

1. create the index
2. and then subset.

To illustrate this (using @akrun's data):

```
require(data.table)
getOption("datatable.auto.index") # [1] TRUE ===> enabled

set.seed(24)
DT <- data.table(id = 1:1e7, height = sample(c(0, 100:240), 1e7, replace = TRUE))

system.time(DT[height == 0L])
#   0.396   0.059   0.452 ## first run
#   0.003   0.000   0.004 ## second run is very fast
```

Now if we disable auto indexing:

```
require(data.table)
options(datatable.auto.index = FALSE)
getOption("datatable.auto.index") # [1] FALSE

set.seed(24)
DT <- data.table(id = 1:1e7, height = sample(c(0, 100:240), 1e7, replace = TRUE))

system.time(DT[height == 0L])
#   0.037   0.007   0.042 ## first run
#   0.039   0.010   0.045 ## second run (~ 10x slower than 2nd run above)

options(datatable.auto.index = TRUE) # restore auto indexing if necessary
```

But your case is special because, you update the same column you subset. In essence, this is what is happening:

1. The `i` expression is seen to be an expression that can be optimised for auto indexing. An index is created and saved for blazing fast subsets later on.
2. The `j` expression is seen and the column is updated.
3. The column on which the index has been set has been updated. So index is removed.

Auto indexing logic should detect this and skip creating the index altogether if any of the rows evaluate to `TRUE`, since the created index is essentially useless.

Could you please file an issue on the [project issues page](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues)? Just linking to this SO Q should be sufficient.

To answer your Q, disable auto indexing and run the subset, and it should be more or less equal to the time you get with `set()`.

Base R solution just can not be faster here since it copies to entire column just to update those entries. But it is because base R chose to do that.

Answer (score 6):

A speed test with one evaluation on 100 million rows:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(id = 1:1e8, 
                 height = sample(c(0, 100:240), 1e8, replace = TRUE))
DT2 <- copy(DT);DT3 <- copy(DT); DT4 <- copy(DT); DT5 <- copy(DT); DT6 <- copy(DT);DT7 <- copy(DT)
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  David    = set(DT, i = which(DT[["height"]] == 0), j = "height", value = NA),
  OP       = DT2[height == 0, height := NA],
  akrun    = setkey(DT3, "height")[.(0), height := NA],
  isna     = {is.na(DT4$height) <- DT4$height == 0},
  assignNA = {DT5$height[DT5$height == 0] <- NA},
  indexset = {setindex(DT6, height); DT6[height==0, height := NA_real_]},
  exponent = DT7[, height:= NA^(!height)*height],
  times=1L
)
# Unit: milliseconds
# expr            min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
# David      585.9044   585.9044   585.9044   585.9044   585.9044   585.9044     1
# OP       10421.3323 10421.3323 10421.3323 10421.3323 10421.3323 10421.3323     1
# akrun    11922.5951 11922.5951 11922.5951 11922.5951 11922.5951 11922.5951     1
# isna      4843.3623  4843.3623  4843.3623  4843.3623  4843.3623  4843.3623     1
# assignNA  4797.0191  4797.0191  4797.0191  4797.0191  4797.0191  4797.0191     1
# indexset  6307.4564  6307.4564  6307.4564  6307.4564  6307.4564  6307.4564     1
# exponent  1054.6013  1054.6013  1054.6013  1054.6013  1054.6013  1054.6013     1
```

Comment: In the first run, the assignment takes place, so in subsequent runs I am not sure how this gives an unbiased benchmark unless you are creating the dataset in each run.

Comment: There is a separate table for each run. They are not connected.

Comment: @Pierre But you are using 10 evals.

Comment: I noticed that, but  what i am saying is after the first run, the assignment already happened.

Comment: We can create and run the function multiple times in `replicate(100, {build DT; set na expression})` that way build overhead is the same for each

Comment: That's an interesting idea if you can afford the memory. Also, gotta make your own summarization function I guess (instead of taking advantage of microbenchmark).

Answer (score 5):

We can try

```
system.time(DT[, height:= NA^(!height)*height])
#  user  system elapsed 
#  0.03    0.05    0.08
```

OP's code

```
system.time(DT[height == 0, height := NA])
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.42    0.04    0.49
```

`base R` option that should be faster.

```
system.time(DT$height[DT$height == 0] <- NA)
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.19    0.05    0.23
```

and the `is.na` route

```
system.time(is.na(DT$height) <- DT$height == 0)
#  user  system elapsed 
#   0.22    0.06    0.28
```

@DavidArenburg's suggestion

```
system.time(set(DT, i = which(DT[["height"]] == 0), j = "height", value = NA))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.06    0.00    0.06
```

NOTE: All these benchmarks are done by freshly creating the dataset before each run so as to provide some unbiased benchmarks.  I could use `microbenchmark`, but there could be some biasedness in each run as the assignment happens in the 1st run.

**Using a bigger dataset**

```
set.seed(24)
DT <- data.table(id = 1:1e8, 
             height = sample(c(0, 100:240), 1e8, replace = TRUE))

system.time(DT[, height:= NA^(!height)*height])
#  user  system elapsed 
#  0.58    0.24    0.81 

system.time(set(DT, i = which(DT[["height"]] == 0), j = "height", value = NA))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.49    0.12    0.61
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
DT <- data.table(id = 1:1e7, 
             height = sample(c(0, 100:240), 1e7, replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: 'setkey(DT, "height")[.(0), height := NA]' is the slowest solution so far. Four times slower than data.frame's 'DT$height[DT$height == 0] <- NA'.

Comment: @snoram It will be fastest in subsequent runs.

Comment: @akrun data.table sets secondary keys, so `DT[height == 0, height := NA]` also will be faster in subsequent runs

Comment: Also, it is interesting to see the improvement in performance if `height` is integer, possibly helpful to the OP.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I am benchmarking from the original dataset. i.e.creating the data again after each run.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Your `set` is fastest in the elapsed time

Comment: Can anyone explain what is happening what this `(!height)*height` trick is?

Comment: @snoram  `!height` gives a logical vector of TRUE/FALSE for height =0 /others.  It can be also written as `height ==0`  Using `NA^(!height)` changes the TRUE value i.e 0 values to NA and all others 1, then by multiplying with `height` any number that multiplies with NA returns NA and with 1 returns the value.